# Security issues in third party HTML content

Tags: html

I have a site currently under development which I allow users to post comments. I want to know if there is a potential security issue if a user maliciously posts HTML elements. I know allowing javascript or CSS is dangerous, but what about HTML?

Comment: You should strip away potentially dangerous / malicious tags such as `<iframe>`, `<script>`, etc.

Comment: This is too broad, also you have options to sanitize user inputs, tag the server side language you are using

Comment: @Mr.Alien I use PHP as server side language

Comment: I agree with @Mr.Alien, your question is much too broad and can be solved with multiple solutions. It also depends on your current code (how you allow comments to be posted, etc.) plus any JS that could already be affecting your comment form.

Comment: @rosemary you should refer tutorials, functions like htmlspecialchars comes handy in these cases, also, using striptags will help you get rid of any tag completely,  but htmlspecialchars is always preferable,  again, depends on what are you looking for, moreover consider using pdo

Comment: @Mr.Alien Thanks again for your valuable tips. I am migrating from mysql to mysqli. Is there any advantage in pdo than mysqli?

Comment: @rosemary many many advantages, pdo supports many databases, porting from one database to another won't be a hectic task anymore,  whereas mysqli functions are bound to mysql only.. apart from this, you can use prepared statements, thus you minimalize sql injections.. refer this article for detailed information http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Comment: And some friendly advice if you care to read this, if you find pdo complicated at first, don't give up, just stick to it.. trust me you will find it really good once you start using..

Comment: @Mr.Alien many many thanks for your kind advice. But as far as I know, prepared statements can also be used in mysqli ?

Comment: @rosemary you can use mysqli in pdo, but that won't make sense, as you will lose database portability option :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are security issues like iframe as mentioned in the comments.  OWASP has a very detailed page on dealing with 3rd party content here:  https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet .

Various languages offer libraries to deal with this:

- Rails: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html
- PHP: http://htmlpurifier.org/comparison

Answer (score 0):

Many different HTML elements can be used in malicious ways, though iframe and script are the worst. The safest solution is to allow a formatting-only language such as Markdown that can easily be used with most server-side languages.